# Codeigniter routing without controller using slug

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I am trying to route the URL. Its working nice is localhost but not working in server. I am using HMVC in codeigniter where 'home' is the module and product is controller. I want to routes if my url structure comes like mentioned.

```
$1 - main category slug
$2 - brand category slug
$3 - model category slug
$4 - product ID
$5 = product title
```

### Routes.php

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'home/product/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5';
```

In which home is the name of directory and product is controller. And my code is as follows:

Product.php (Controller)

```
  function _remap() {
    $this->index();
  }

function index() {
    $segs = $this->uri->segment_array();
    .
    .
    $product_id = $this->uri->segment(4);
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: how about `site_url()`?

Comment: Which type of error are you getting?

Comment: Have you tried putting function after product `$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'home/product/index/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5';`

Comment: I am getting 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 404 error because you have not written method name in url
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'home/product/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5';

> It should be like this
>
> $route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:num)/(:any)'] = home/product/index/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5';

Comment: No It is not the problem.